# Variation of $l_p$ norm limit is $l_\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, vector-spaces

Let $\mathbb{R}^d$ be the ambience space. I am aware of the result $\| x \|_{l_p} \to \| x \|_{l_\infty}$ as $p \to \infty$. I wonder, if on the other hand, we know $x_p \to x$ as $p \to \infty$ and $x_p \in l_p$ for all $p$, do we have $\| x_p \|_{l_p} \to \| x \|_{l_\infty}$? If not, is there a condition that is strong enough for this to be true?

Comment: Are the $x$'s sequences or vectors in $\mathbb R^d$ ? In the second case the answer is direct as all norms are equivalent

Comment: @Stratossupportsthestrike They are vectors. Could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Note that $\|x_p\|_{\infty} \le \|x_p\|_{\ell_p} \le d^{\frac{1}{p}} \|x_p\|_{\infty}$. What is the limit of $\|x_p\|_{\ell_\infty}$? How it helps you to conclude?

Comment: All norms are equivalent, so $\| x_p \|_\infty \to \| x \|_\infty$ and thus by the squeeze theorem we get $\| x_p \|_p \to \| x \|_\infty$?

Comment: Yes, or more directly, from $x_p \to x$ (presumably by that you mean convergence in euclidean distance (?)) we simply get that every coordinate of $x_p$ must converge to appropriate coordinate of $x$, and hence also $\|x_p\|_{\infty}$ converges to $\|x\|_\infty$.